# Is there a measure on any measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S})$? ("Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.

Let $X$ be a set.
Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.
Then, $(X,\mathcal{S})$ is called a measurable space. (See the following definition in this book.)

> The word *measurable* is used in the terminology below because in the next section we introduce a size function, called a measure, defined on measurable sets.

> 2.26 **Definition** ***measurable space; measurable se***t
>
> - A *measurable space* is an ordered pair $(X,\mathcal{S})$, where $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.
> - An element of $\mathcal{S}$ is called an *$\mathcal{S}$-measurable set*, or just a *measurable set* if $\mathcal{S}$ is clear from the context.

$(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ is a measurable space and outer measure is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$.
$(\mathbb{R},2^\mathbb{R})$ is a measurable space and outer measure is not a measure on $(\mathbb{R},2^\mathbb{R})$.

If $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, then we call $(X,\mathcal{S})$ a measurable space.
So, we expect there exists a measure on any measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S})$.
Is there a measure on any measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S})$?

---

I noticed that the zero function $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to [0,\infty]$ is a measure on $(X,\mathcal{S})$.

Let $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to [0,\infty]$ be a function such that $\mu(E)=\infty$ for any $E\subset X$ which is not empty and $\mu(\emptyset)=0.$
I think this $\mu$ is also a measure on $(X,\mathcal{S})$.

But these functions are trivial.

Is there a nontrivial measure on any measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S})$? (But I cannot define a trivial measure exactly.)

---

I am very sorry.
The author wrote very interesting examples of measures in Example 2.55 on p.41.
The second bullet point in Example 2.55 and the third bullet point in Exmaple 2.55 are nontrivial measures on any measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S})$.

Comment: Let $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to [0,\infty]$ be a zero function. Then $\mu$ is a measure on $(X,\mathcal{S})$. Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a nontrivial measure, the point mass
\begin{align*}
\delta_x(E) &= \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } x\in E; \\
    0 & \text{if } x\not\in E
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for any fixed $x\in X$ is a measure for any $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal S}$ on $X$.

Comment: anomaly, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @tchappyha or the counting measure

Comment: @peek-a-boo The author wrote: If $X$ is a set, then counting measure is the measure $\mu$ defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of $X$ by setting $\mu(E)=n$ if $E$ is a finite set containing exactly $n$ elements and $\mu(E)=\infty$ if $E$ is not a finite set. But I didn't notice this is a measure on any measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S}).$ If $\mu$ is a measure on $(X,2^X)$, then $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to [0,\infty]$ is also a measure on any measurable space $(X,\mathcal{S}).$ Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: The author wrote: "Suppose $X$ is a set, $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and $w:X\to [0,\infty]$ is a function. Define a measure $\mu$ on $(X,\mathcal{S})$ by $\mu(E)=\sum_{x\in E} w(x)$ for $E\in\mathcal{S}.$ [Here the sum is defined as the supremum of all finite subsums $\sum_{x\in D} w(x)$ as $D$ ranges over all finite subsets of $E$.]" I noticed if $w:X\to [0,\infty]$ is a function such that $w(x)=1$ for any $x\in X$, then $\mu$ which is defined above is the counting measure on $(X,\mathcal{S}).$ Thank you.

Comment: @tchappyha: No thanks are necessary, but you're welcome.